# Select2 doesnt load method from Controller in DataTable ajax

Tags: jquery, datatable, jquery-select2

I have Select2 in DataTable But Select2 doesn't load.
"GetCompany" Methode doesnt call from Controller.
would you please help me?
there is my code :
there is my code :
there is my code :
there is my code :
there is my code :

```
$('#tblQuestion').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/FormQuestion/FormQuestion/GetQuestionListByFormId",
        "data": function (data) {
            data.formId = $("#formId").val()
        },
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) { 
                return ' <select class="select" id="drpCompany"  style="width:400px"></select>  ';
            },
        },
    ],
    drawCallback: function (settings) {  
        $(".select").select2();  
    }
});
  

$("#drpCompany").select2({  
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        ajax: {
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Company/Company/GetCompany",
            data: '{}',
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        return {

                            text: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        },
    }).on('change', function (e) {
        var getID = $(this).select2('data');
        $("#companyId_Selected").val(getID[0]['id']);
    });
```

Comment: Please don't add repeated text _" there is my code : there is my code : there is my code : there is my code"_, just to pad the question. Instead, see if you can improve the question, so this is not needed. For example, what data does your code handle? Can you provide your code as a [mre]? Are there any errors when you run your code? If so, what are they? (Note also that HTML IDs are supposed to be unique in a page - so if you use `id="drpCompany"` in multiple rows, then the ID will not be unique.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have this:

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {  
  $(".select").select2();  
}
```

This will only build empty select2 drop-downs, with no values.

The code below this - `$('.select').select2({ ... })` - will not find any select2 items to select, because it runs (asynchronously) before the DataTable has finished rendering them.

You can re-arrange your code to handle this - for example:

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
  buildSelect2();
}
```

...and then place your select2 initialization code in that function:

```
function buildSelect2() {
  $('.select').select2({
    // your initialization code...
  });
}
```

Note that in the above code, I am using the class selector `'.select'` and not the ID selector. In fact, I removed the ID selector from the HTML:

```
return ' <select class="select" style="width:400px"></select>  ';
```

This is because these IDs would not be unique if your DataTable has more than one row of data in it.

After the above changes, you should see your drop-downs being populated.

---

The following is not in scope for your question, but I think it is worth mentioning.

You still need to handle filtering logic, as the user types text into each search. Currently, your select2 Ajax requests are hard-coded to always send an empty object:

```
data: '{}'
```

If you want the user to be able to filter the list, you need to fix this, also.

You need to use the select2 [request parameters](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#request-parameters) to handle this.

To start fixing that, you need to remove that `data: '{}'`.

After doing that, your Ajax requests will contain POST bodies like this:

```
term=z&_type=query&q=z
```

where the `term` value (here is is `z`) is whatever the user has typed into the search box. Your server-side code needs to use this to filter the select options it places in its Ajax response.